# ios how to extract all rangeOfString of an array in a for loop?

Tags: ios, for-loop, range

I want to extract all "daughter" of a NSarray.

For example, nsarray is made like this:

```
hello
hi
hello daughter
my goodness
daughter (someone)
my daughter
how are you?
etc.
```

And I want to extract all lines that contain "daughter". Could you point me in right direction?

My current code is:

```
for (NSString *mystring in self.array)
{
    if ([mystring rangeOfString:searchText].location!=NSNotFound)

{
   NSUInteger idx = [self.array indexOfObject:mystring];
   [self.filterarray addObject: mystring];
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *lines = ...;
NSArray *filteredLines = [lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([string rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
}]];
```

(requires iOS 4.0 or later)

If you need to support earlier system versions use this:

```
NSArray *lines = ...;
NSArray *filteredLines = [lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains[c] %@)", searchText]];
```

(requires iOS 3.0 or later)

Comment: What is minimum ios for this?

Comment: `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` exists since iOS 3.0 and `predicateWithBlock:` since iOS 4.0.

Comment: self.filterarray is a nsmutablearray, how do I add objects to it with your codes? I get warning after writing ´ self.filterarray = [self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id string, NSDictionary *bindings) {
  return ([string rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
 }]];´ warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *' when passing argument 1 of 'setFilteredListContent:' from distinct Objective-C type

Comment: Ok, is it possible not using predicateWithBlock:?

Comment: @wagashi: yes, see my updated answer. for adding the items to `self.filterarray` use `[self.filterarray addObjectsFromArray:[lines filtered...]]`

Comment: I believe it works, but in my case it crashes, I must investigate intot it someday. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *textViewText = @“hello hi hello daughter my goodness daughter (someone) my daughter how are you? etc.”;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textViewText];


NSArray *highlightWords = @[@“daughter”,@”hello”];

for(NSString *word in highlightWords)
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, textViewText.length);
    do{
        range = [textViewText rangeOfString:word options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + 1, textViewText.length - (range.location + 1));
    }while(range.location != NSNotFound);

}
```